# Oledbconnection to Access Database C#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I face some problem:

I can insert data to my database by following code:

```
oledbconnection = new oledbconnection (@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data 
                                   Source=C:\User\yourdbfile.accdb");
```

the data was successfully insert to my database,

but if i change the code to

```
oledbconnection = new oledbconnection (@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data 
                             Source=yourdbfile.accdb");
```

**OR**

```
oledbconnection = new oledbconnection (@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data 
                       Source=|DataDirectory|\yourdbfile.accdb");
```

I'm unable to insert data to database, and there is no error.

---

Another Question,

How can i publish my system with database file? because when i installed this system on another pc, the error show `C:\User\yourdbfile.accdb` not found.

Comment: Copy `yourdbfile.accdb` file in your project via solution explorer and use `|DataDirectory|\yourdbfile.accdb`.

Comment: my "yourdbfile.accdb" already in my project. @AVD

Comment: i think yourdbfile.accdb should be in your App data folder!

Comment: @Mullaly App Data folder meant?

Comment: Its App_Data folder(ita a folder creased by visual studio on creating a project)..Maybe this will help you.. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296

Answer (score 0):

U can put the db source file into the application folder,e.g: install disk folder :d:\AA\BB\ ,
DB file :D:\AA\BB\DB file\

Comment: change the connectString:oledbconnection = new oledbconnection (@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+Application .LocalUserAppDataPath);     and attach the db file in the installation path when publich the app

Comment: oledbconnection = new oledbconnection (@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+Application .LocalUserAppDataPath);
like this only?

Comment: What lexeRoy said that is the better way to fix this

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the Property of the Access file on its Build property value.

**OR**

Modifying your ProjectName.csproj is a better way to over come with this problem. See details below:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(OutputPath)yourdbfile.accdb" DestinationFolder="$(YourVariable)" ContinueOnError="true" />
</Target>
```

See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx) for your reference.

After checking those things, You can now use:

```
var oledbconnection = new Oledbconnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=yourdbfile.accdb");
```

Comment: <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(OutputPath)yourdbfile.accdb" DestinationFolder="$(YourVariable)" ContinueOnError="true" />
</Target>
this coding is needed to put on my project?

Comment: `$(YourVariable)` is just an example of Build Command, You can choose where do you want to build it. For example replace it with `$(TargetDir)`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx